# How can I create a frosted glass effect (glassmorphism) in react native like ios provides?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, ui-design, react-native-blur

[You can check here iOS Blurry Effect Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsrm7.png)

I tried [react-native-blur](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-blur) and [react-native-skia](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/) packages but couldn't achieve the same thing like the ios native provides for their general views.